# Autorun.inf opens a batch file which creates a directory doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, autorun

I'm trying to make a autorun.inf file which would open a .bat file from a flash drive.

What I have in the autorun.inf file:

```
[autorun]
open=launch.bat
icon=icon.ico
```

What I have in the launch.bat file:

```
@echo off
::start

mkdir "C:\ThisIsATest"

exit
```

When I have inserted the flash drive to my personal computer, I have noticed that the icon of the drive has changed, but I can't see the effect of the launch.bat file.
I have tried the batch file to see if it works and it works. Thus, I believe that the autorun.inf file doesn't work.

As I have read from the Internet, it matters that I have Windows 8 and Windows 7.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autorun.inf` is not executed anymore on flash drives. These days it only works for CD's or DVD's, but the user still needs to allow it first.

Comment: Yes. I have read about something like this. But what should do the user to allow the autoplay.inf to run? On the computer where I have tried the flash drive, it doesn't pop up any message to inform the user about the flash drive. In addition, I have checked in the Control Panel if the AutoPlay is used for all media and devices.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with trying to get autorun.inf to run, it won't happen and you cannot expect your users to change any settings to make it work.

Comment: @Sony: Read again what ZippyV wrote: autorun.inf is not executed from flash drives. It's not going to prompt the user for permission, because **it is not executed**. There is no setting to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that making the folder in C: needs Admin rights?
Try creating the folder on the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:

```
[autorun] 
icon=icon.ico
open=launch.bat
action=Click to run.
shell\open\command=launch.bat
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** You could also try compiling your batch file into a exe using this: http://www.battoexeconverter.com/

Try having a look here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/216706-autoplay-enable-disable.html

Comment: Try doing it the exe way.

Comment: As far as i can see it should work but due to windows been over protective this could be stopping it. Try putting it on to a disk.

Comment: Yes. It is really protective because it doesn't want to run it. I will try it on Windows XP to see if it works.