# Execute an command after reading/accessing an directory

Tags: windows, cmd, autorun

Every time I borrow someone my USB flash drive I tell them "but do not look into 'horses' directory" (which actually is empty). I'm curious, how many of my friends had accessed this directory. I have run into idea, that I could write a script that will increment some counter (or create empty file in another location on flash drive), so I could determine the amount of people that actually accessed the directory.

I thinking about autorun.inf files, but it seems like this feature is disabled, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384608/autorun-inf-opens-a-batch-file-which-creates-a-directory-doesnt-work). Event if somehow I could manage to do this, I'm not sure if antivirus will not rise an warning.

So, is there a way to do this simple, or the cake is not worth the candle?

Comment: Well that could be exploited for so kany malicious activities. If you still intend to do, I can think of an idea. You write a batch script ro do whatever you desire (like reading a hidden txt file, incrementing a counter, saving it and then exiting) and change its icon to folder's icon with the name you want.

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava I'm aware that it could be malicious, so probably OS is secured for this. Nevertheless, I think the effort is to big to achieve so little, so I will abandon this idea.